# Make the frameset of a frameset scrollable?

Tags: html, frameset

First off, I know how to make a frameset scrollable.

The problem is I have a frameset within a frameset within a frameset.

I want to make it so that if the frameset of the frameset of the frameset overflows in the x direction, I get a scrollbar for the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

what the heck??? Please show an image or a code snippet. I have no idea what you are talking about.

What I think you mean: How do I make the page scroll in the x direction?

simple. Make sure that the background image is larger than most computer screens

Please clarify and I will be able to help you.